# Anchoring a Form in vb.net 2010

Tags: winforms, anchor, vb.net-2010

my question is how to anchor a child mdi to its parent mdi so that each time the user expands or minimizes the parent form the child form automatically follows. I already tried to use the resize function in form but it doesn't help 
thanks all help is appriciated

Comment: I don't think it's possible. MDI parent and child are in a different relationship, child is not supposed to react to parent size in any way, unless a child is docked/maximized.

Comment: so that means that i cant change the size of a child form programmatically ?  i was hoping to get the size of the parent form each time it was being resize then equate it to the size of the child form

Comment: You *can* do that, but it does not mean you should. There are certain expectation a user has when working with an MDI interface. One of them is what I described.

Comment: If you really want that functionality, you need to implement it manually by handling MDIParent's Resize or ResizeBegin and ResizeEnd handlers - I'll try to get a sample project working for you as time allows.

Answer (score 0):

See below - a quick version I wrote, which seems to handle most anchoring scenarios. You may need to polish this code a bit. But this should get you started:

```vb
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class MDIChildForm
  Dim p_eMyAnchor As AnchorStyles
  Dim p_mdiParent As Form

  Dim p_iOldHeight, p_iOldWidth As Integer

  <DefaultValue(AnchorStyles.Left Or AnchorStyles.Top)>
  Public Property MyAnchor As AnchorStyles
    Get
      Return p_eMyAnchor
    End Get
    Set(value As AnchorStyles)
      p_eMyAnchor = value
      chkAnchorTop.Checked = (p_eMyAnchor And AnchorStyles.Top)
      chkAnchorLeft.Checked = (p_eMyAnchor And AnchorStyles.Left)
      chkAnchorRight.Checked = (p_eMyAnchor And AnchorStyles.Right)
      chkAnchorBottom.Checked = (p_eMyAnchor And AnchorStyles.Bottom)
    End Set
  End Property

  Sub New()
    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    p_eMyAnchor = AnchorStyles.Left Or AnchorStyles.Top
  End Sub

  Public Sub ShowAsMDIChild(mdiParent As Form)
    p_mdiParent = mdiParent
    Me.MdiParent = mdiParent
    AddHandler mdiParent.ResizeBegin, AddressOf MDIParentForm_ResizeBegin
    AddHandler mdiParent.ResizeEnd, AddressOf MDIParentForm_ResizeEnd
    Me.Show()
  End Sub

  Private Sub MDIParentForm_ResizeBegin(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim frm As Form = DirectCast(sender, Form)
    p_iOldWidth = frm.Width
    p_iOldHeight = frm.Height
  End Sub

  Private Sub MDIParentForm_ResizeEnd(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim parentForm As Form = DirectCast(sender, Form)

    'handling for horizontal anchoring
    Dim deltaWidth As Integer = parentForm.Width - p_iOldWidth
    Dim fAnchorLeft As Boolean = p_eMyAnchor And AnchorStyles.Left
    Dim fAnchorRight As Boolean = p_eMyAnchor And AnchorStyles.Right

    Select Case fAnchorLeft
      Case True : If fAnchorRight Then Me.Width += deltaWidth
      Case False
        Dim coef As Single = If(fAnchorRight, 1, 0.5)
        Me.Left += deltaWidth * coef
    End Select

    'handling for vertical anchoring
    Dim deltaHeight As Integer = parentForm.Height - p_iOldHeight
    Dim fAnchorTop As Boolean = p_eMyAnchor And AnchorStyles.Top
    Dim fAnchorBottom As Boolean = p_eMyAnchor And AnchorStyles.Bottom

    Select Case fAnchorTop
      Case True : If fAnchorBottom Then Me.Height += deltaHeight
      Case False
        Dim coef As Single = If(fAnchorBottom, 1, 0.5)
        Me.Top += deltaHeight * coef
    End Select
  End Sub

End Class
```

For horizonal anchoring, the following rules are used:

- left - nothing happens (default behavior)
- left and right - expand width to parent form width delta
- right - move left by parent form width delta
- no anchor - move left by half parent form width delta.

Same principle applies to vertical anchoring, for top and bottom respectively.

You can get the full project to play with [here (Mediafire)](http://www.mediafire.com/download/gvmeygagktgfa2j/AnchorMDIChild.zip).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Me.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom
Me.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left
Me.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Right
Me.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top
```